# Django - Global name 'PayLaneRestClient' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I am having a issue while importing a class and trying to use it from Django's views.py. I have the following error : `global name 'PayLaneRestClient' is not defined`.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from polls import paylane_rest_client

def form(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def submit(request):
    client = PayLaneRestClient(log, pw)
    try:
        status = client.card_sale_by_token(card_params)
    except Exception, e:
        print e
    if client.is_success():
        print 'Success, id_sale: %s' % status['id_sale']
    else:
        sys.exit('Error ID: ' + str(status["error"]["id_error"]) + '\n' \
        'Error number: ' + str(status["error"]["error_number"]) + '\n' \
        'Error description: ' + str(status["error"]["error_description"]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before calling any API methods, make sure that you have properly initiated the PayLane Rest Client as follows:

`from client import PayLaneRestClient`

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. I had just to replace 'client' by the name of my python file.